# Decide on class at runtime at write all fields to file in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have a system that writes reports to a file in json. All three reports share fields like id and value but each report has additional fields that are not shared. I want to decide at runtime which report I want to write based on some value supplied to the main function. How can I keep the code flexible so this is possible?

The reports have the following fields

```
Report A - id, value, agreementId
Report B - id, value, tierId
Report C - id, value, instanceId
```

I'd like to have something like this

```
Report report = // either report a, b, or c
Files.write(outputDirectory.resolve("report.json"), gson.toJson(report).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
```

and have all 3 fields present depending on what value is supplied to select the correct report type.

I tried using an abstract class report and extending it for the other three reports. But it hides the third field and only writes the first two.

Comment: Does each of your three subclasses have public get-methods for the additional property?  (Meaning, ReportA has a public `getAgreementId` method, ReportB has a public `getTierId` method, and ReportC has a public `getInstanceId` method.)

Answer (score 1):

So at runtime you have some class in front of you, not knowing it's exact type at compile time and therefore not knowing of the fields and methods to retrieve data.

Java offers the Reflection API that you can use to ask an Object about it's class, and from there find out about fields and methods. Ultimately you can retrieve field values and also call methods using Reflection.

Have a look at the fine [Oracle Tutorial for the Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Another option, without Reflection would be to have a common superclass. That superclass would have one method, say `String toJSON()` that would simply return a JSON String. As this method is overridden in your report classes they know exactly what class, methods and fields are available and thus can deliver a nice report to your taste. Easier than Reflection and a good learning path into parent classes and subclasses and polymorphism.